# Django and wordpress on nginx 404 error

Tags: django, wordpress, nginx

I have a django running on example.com, i need add a Wordpress to my server, would be example.com/blog, perhaps doesnt work (404 error):

```
listen      80;
server_name www.example.com;    

location ^~ /blog/ {
        root    /www/blog;
        index   index.html index.htm index.php;
        try_files  $uri =404;

        location ~ \.php {
                root /www/blog;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.*\.php)(.*)$;
                include fastcgi_params;

                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }

}

location / {
    uwsgi_pass  unix:/tmp/myapp.sock;
    include     /www/webapp/system/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    uwsgi_read_timeout 300;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Levi configuration give me some light, i need to modify because i'm getting 404 error or No input file especified.

```
    location /blog {
         alias    /www/blog;

        try_files $uri $uri/ index.php?$args;
        index index.php;

        location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;

            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /www/blog$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;

            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran in this problem too. Here, you can check my location config.

```
location /blog {
    root /var/www/html; 

    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
    index index.php; 

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) { 
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;

        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php; 
    } 

}
```

Adapted for your config:

```
location /blog {
     root    /www/blog; 

    try_files $uri $uri/ index.php?$args;
    index index.php; 

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) { 
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;

        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php; 
    } 

}
```

Comment: wordpress folder is /www/blog/index.php but nginx is searching in "/usr/share/nginx/htmlindex.php"

Comment: @user2925795 I think you should let the / in /index.php? But I don't know why are u getting 404.

Comment: Is giving 404 coz he searches wordpress in "/usr/share/nginx/htmlindex.php"  ... where he should look in / www/blog/ how i change this?

Comment: @user2925795 add  /  to index.php, like this : `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;`